# Google App Engine SDK Fatal Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I installed Python 3.4 on my Mac (OS 10.9.3) and my command for running Google App Engine from the terminal via /usr/local/dev_appengine stopped working. I then (stupidly) did some rather arbitrary things from online help forums and now my Google App Engine itself stopped working as well. When I open it, it says:

*Sorry, pieces of GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app appear missing or corrupted, or I can't run python2.5 properly.  Output was:*

I have tried to delete the application and all related files and reinstall, but nothing has worked for me. It now fails to make the command symlinks as well so when I try to run from terminal I get /usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py: No such file or directory.

Comment: Did you make sure your app.yaml file line specifying your version of python matches the version of python you're using? `runtime: python27`

Comment: @Ryan Oh. Yes I still have `runtime python27` in my yaml.app. Since GAEfan says that GAE doesn't support python3x I suppose I should leave it as that. So I imagine I must have messed with the python27 links or folders when I installed python34. Unfortunately I still don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine does not support Python 3.x.  Do you still have 2.x installed?  Go to your Google App Engine Launcher > Preferences, and make sure you have the proper Python Path to your v2.x.  It should be something like "/usr/bin/python2.7"

From Terminal, type`whereis python` to help find it.  If you know you were using version 2.7, try: `whereis python2.7`

Comment: Thanks. whereis python gives me /usr/bin/python. The problem is I can't even get into the GAE preferences since it aborts after the error message above.

Comment: make sure you do `whereis python2.7`, to make sure you still have it, and get the right path

Comment: OK I tried `whereis python2.7` (and `whereis python27`) and for each it gave no output. But when I look for all the python folders in /usr/bin/ I get 
`/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python2.5
/usr/bin/python2.5-config
/usr/bin/python2.6
/usr/bin/python2.6-config
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/bin/pythonw
/usr/bin/pythonw2.5
/usr/bin/pythonw2.6
/usr/bin/pythonw2.7`